# How to get app usage report in G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I want to know how many users have installed my add-on this month, which is published on G Suite Marketplace. In G Suite Marketplace SDK there is a usage tab, but i can't find any filter or time period selection option. I aslo tried the download option but it also gives the same data which is in the chart.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how can i know the number of installation last month?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the accumulated downloads through time, can't you get the downloads per month by calculating the difference between two points in time?

Comment: yeah, but then i have to save the accumulated downloads at the last date of each month, because this chart only have data for past 20 days or so

Comment: I don't think you can older data while on the `Usage` tab from the console. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/faq#how_can_i_get_information_about_app_usage), though, you could use `Licensing API` to get the count of installations (see [LicenseNotification: list](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list)) for your app.

Comment: You can set a `timestamp` filter to only get the installations after a specified time, and call this with different times to get the installation count for a specified interval. Do you think this workaround would be useful for your situation?